# How to insert into database invoice and products in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel

I need some help inserting into database invoice and products from the same form. I have had so many errors.

Invoice database:

```
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('invoice_no');
    $table->date('invoice_date');
    $table->date('due_date');
    $table->string('title');
    $table->string('client');
    $table->string('client_address');
    $table->decimal('subtotal');
    $table->decimal('grandtotal');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Product database:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('invoice_id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('qty');
    $table->string('price');
    $table->string('total');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Invoice model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'client',
    'client_address',
    'title',
    'invoice_no',
    'invoice_date',
    'due_date',
    'discount',
    'subtotal',
    'grandtotal'
];
```

Product model:

```
public function products() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product', 'invoice_id');
}

protected $casts = [
    'name' => 'array',
    'price' => 'array',
    'qty' => 'array',
    'total' => 'array'
];

protected $fillable = ['invoice_id','price','qty','total','name'];

public function invoice() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Invoice');
}
```

Invoice controller:

```
$invoice = new Invoice();
$invoice->invoice_no = $request->invoice_no;
$invoice->client = $request->client;
$invoice->title = $request->title;
$invoice->client_address = $request->client_address;
$invoice->invoice_date = $request->invoice_date;
$invoice->due_date = $request->due_date;
$invoice->subtotal = $request->subtotal;
$invoice->grandtotal = $request->grandtotal;

$input = $request->all();
$product = new Product();
$product->name = $input['name'];
$product->price = $input['price'];
$product->qty = $input['qty'];
$product->total = $input['total'];

$invoice->save();
$product->invoice_id = $invoice->id;
$invoice->products()->save($product);
```

Comment: what are the so many errors?

Comment: ErrorException in HasOneOrMany.php line 221:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, boolean given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/angie/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php on line 237 and defined

Comment: Please ask one error message per question and include only the code that is relevant to the error message in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an invoice that has many products. So, first create your invoice

```
$invoice = \Invoice::create([
    'invoice_no' => $request->invoice_no,
    'client' => $request->client,
    'title' => $request->title,
    'client_address' => $request->client_address,
    'invoice_date' => $request->invoice_date,
    'due_date' => $request->due_date,
    'subtotal' => $request->subtotal,
    'grandtotal' => $request->grandtotal
]);
```

And then, add its products

```
$product = $invoice->products()->create([        
    'name' => $request->name,
    'price' => $request->price,
    'qty' => $request->qty,
    'total' => $request->total
])
```

If you have more than one product, put the product creation in a foreach loop.

How you manage the insertion of your products, depends on your form structure. In the continue, I will give you an example of the whole process.

I assume that this is your form:

```
<form>                                
    <div class="product">
        <input name="products[0][name]" >
        <input name="products[0][price]" >
        <input name="products[0][qty]" >
        <input name="products[0][total]" >            
    </div>

    <div class="product">
        <input name="products[1][name]" >
        <input name="products[1][price]" >
        <input name="products[1][qty]" >
        <input name="products[1][total]" >            
    </div>

    <div class="product">
        <input name="products[2][name]" >
        <input name="products[2][price]" >
        <input name="products[2][qty]" >
        <input name="products[2][total]" >            
    </div>

    <button type="submit" >Submit</button>    
</form>
```

After submitting the form, you will have an array of your products:

```
$request->products
```

returns

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'some name',
        'price' => '10',
        'qty' => '2',
        'total' => '20',
    ], [
        'name' => 'some name',
        'price' => '10',
        'qty' => '2',
        'total' => '20',
    ], [
        'name' => 'some name',
        'price' => '10',
        'qty' => '2',
        'total' => '20',
    ],
]
```

Now you can insert them in the database like below:

```
foreach($request->products as $product) {
    $invoice->products()->create([        
        'name' => $product['name'],
        'price' => $product['price'],
        'qty' => $product['qty'],
        'total' => $product['total']
    ]);
}
```

OR

```
foreach($request->products as $product) {
    $invoice->products()->create($product);
}
```

Comment: And if you want to prevent breaking of this process because of error or whatever, you can use database transactions. This will ensure that the process of insertion is done successfully or failed (when it fails, noting will insert in database)

Comment: one more question how to add a foreach loop pls? foreach($products as $product) ??

Comment: i did exactly how you showed me however getting this error
Illegal string offset 'name'

Comment: I'm doing the same, no problem!